# add Multiple criterion in condition OR to Criteria

Tags: hibernate

hy all,

i like find a mode to add multiple criterion in condition or.
listCriterions is the list of the criterions

```
 Criteria criteria = this.session.createCriteria(Azienda.class);

 for(Criterion criterion : listCriterions){

    //here i like add all criterion in OR to criteria
  }

  ArrayList<Azienda> listAzienda = new ArrayList<Azienda>();

  listAzienda.addAll(criteria.list());
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

thansk i have find this mode:

```
Criteria criteria = this.session.createCriteria(Azienda.class);
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction(); 
for (Criterion criterion : listCriterions) { 
    disjunction.add(criterion); 
} 
criteria.add(disjunction); 
ArrayList<Azienda> listAzienda = new ArrayList<Azienda>();
listAzienda.addAll(criteria.list());
```